# can't click a column while success getting its content

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a grid table which I'm trying to click one of its column's without any success so far. 
I can get its content\data(of each of the coulmns) , but when clicking on it, the test passes but does not really click on the requested element. either not on the row nor the column.

I tried it in two different ways:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
_webdriver.SwitchTo().Frame("WebResource_kendoHistory");

var tbl = _webdriver.FindElements(By.Id("tblMain"));
var gridmaster = tbl[0].FindElement(By.Id("tdGridMaster"));

var gridcontent = gridmaster.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.k-grid-content"));
var tableselectable = gridcontent
     .FindElement(By.CssSelector("table.k-selectable"));

var tr = tableselectable.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr[role='row']"));
var td = tr[1].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
td[1].Click();
```

And by this as well:

```
var element = wait.Until(
   ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(
       By.CssSelector(".k-selectable tr[role='row']")
   )
);
element.Click();
```

I have tried to make a `Javascript` click as well without any success.

This is part of the Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="k-ie k-ie11">
   <head>
  <title></title>
   </head>
   <body class="k-rtl" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <div class="k-widget k-splitter" id="splitterDiv" data-role="splitter">
     <div class="k-pane k-scrollable" id="incidentsDiv" role="group" >
        <table id="tblMain" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td id="tdGridMaster" colspan="5">
                    <div class="k-grid k-widget" 
                         id="gridMaster" data-role="grid"
                         style="width: 100%; height: 242px;" >
                       <div class="k-grid-content" style="height: 163px;">
                          <table class="k-selectable" role="grid"  
                                 data-role="selectable">
                             <tbody role="rowgroup">
                                <tr role="row" 
                           data-uid="c65559ae-8b2f-4768-9cb9-7a9f7c3dc3ba">
                                   <td>
                   <a style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" 
                   onclick="motherOrBatClicked('null',' ')"> </a>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>2018-4315</td>
                                   <td>incident</td>
                                   <td>חss</td>
                                   <td>2018-8888</td>
                                   <td style="display: none;"> </td>
                                   <td>&lt;sssa1&gt;</td>
                                   <td>Joe</td>
                                   <td>12/04/2018</td>
                                   <td> </td>
                                   <td>Digitar</td>
                                </tr>
                             </tbody>
                          </table>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you click on those <td> elements manually ?

Comment: yes ,manually I can click on those <td> and even <tr>

Comment: I have made a HTML file with the provided code and I can't click on it. Are those <td> or <tr> in anchor tag or in a button ?

Comment: they are in anchor tag, not buttons

Comment: It'd be better if you could share the relevant HTML with <a> tag also.

Comment: in each row , the `<td>` is the last on hierarchy. There is no `<a>` tag. so basically the click should happen for clicking the row or the column. sorry for misleading in the previous message.

Comment: Can you share a link to an example page? Have you tried clicking on the CSS selector `.k-selectable tr[role='row'] > td`? If you run `$$(".k-selectable tr[role='row'] > td")` in the dev console, how many elements does it return? Is the first element it returns one that you want to click?

Comment: I messed up commenting beyond yong's solution, `click one of its column` can you be **specific** with which element are you trying to click exactly? Each and every element will have different solution.

Comment: I'm trying to click a <td> or <tr> element(s). none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbl = _webdriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#tblMain #gridMaster table.k-selectable"));

var firstCell = tbl.FindElement(By.CssSelector("tr[role='row'] > td"));

var firstLink = firstCell.FindElement(By.CssSelector('a'));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(firstLink));

firstLink.click();
```

Comment: Unable to find element with css selector == tblMain #gridMaster table.k-selectable

Comment: `click one of its column` which element are you trying to click exactly?

Comment: @DebanjanB , I'm trying to click a `<td>` or `<tr>` element(s)

Comment: @yong, as before, there element is being found , but I can't submit a click on the row\column